# Avoid select box widening when long option is chosen

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am working with a dashboard, containing panels. Each panel has a limited width as the dashboard contains quite a lot of information.

Each panel contains a table listing certain users and an *Angular* dropdown selector to add more.

When selecting a user whose name is longer than the width of the box, it expands, pushing both the box and the adjacent button out of the panel, even sometimes overlapping the one next to it.

Here's how the element is written in the markup :

```
<td>
       <select chosen style="font-size: 75%" options="users" id="selectedTechnicianUser" ng-model="selectedUser" ng-change="addUser(selectedUser)" class="form-control" search-contains="true" display-selected-options="false" ng-options="<query...>">
       </select>
</td>
```

I would like the name to be cut when needed, ideally by showing something like  `[Jonathan LEI...]`in the box or just, as I had attempted, reducing the size of the font.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use property like     text-overflow: ellipsis;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time spent researching and numerous attempts with the different options, here is what I've learned :

- Since I am using **Angular**, it turns out that modifying the `<select>` tag options isn't useful in this case : the tag creates one `<div>` containing several other `<div>` tags. These use **CSS** styles defined in the bower_components files.
- Depending on the order the files are loaded in, some might overwrite previously set parameters.
- Some attributes, in my case: `width` can be passed a dynamic value (say `width: 100%;` *AND* the `!important` option, overwriting any other value for the same attribute.
- As mentionned by Dipnesh, the option `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is exactly what's needed for this situation, the matter was where to put it so it does its job.